# Admin Details in Backend in Magento 2

Tags: php, database, backend, magento2.2

I have created **admin grid** and associated **UI form**. If I **add** a **new item**, the current **(first)admin** name who added the item should **save** in **DB.** That **(first)admin** name **would not be change**. But if the second admin logged in(using acl) and started to edit the existing items, **while saving the item**, It **changes** the **created person name** as **current admin(Second admin)name**. So please suggest me a solution to overcome this problem,  to make created person name as unchangeable if second admin logged in.

Controller for **save.php**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\HomeSlider\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    )
    {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $postModel = $this->_objectManager->create('OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post');

        if ($id) {
            $postModel = $postModel->load($id);
        }
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('general');
        $user = $this->getCurrentUser();
        $post['created_by'] = $user;
        $post['updated_by'] = $user;
        if(empty($post['id'])) {
            $post['id'] = null;
        }

        if (isset($post['image'])) {
            $post['image'] = $post['image'][0]['name'];
        } else {
            $post['image'] = null;
        }


        $postModel->setData($post);
        $postModel->save();
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('homeslider/post/index');
    }
    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
    }

}
```

Block file **additional_info.php**

```
<?php
namespace OX\HomeSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use OX\HomeSlider\Model\Post;
class AdditionalInfo extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;
    protected $authSession;
    protected $_timezone;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone, \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->_timezone = $timezone;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
    }
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        $postModel = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('homepageslider_post')->getCreatedAt();
        return $date = $this->_timezone->date($postModel)->format('d/m/y H:i:s A');
    }
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        $postModel = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('homepageslider_post')->getUpdatedAt();
        return $date = $this->_timezone->date($postModel)->format('d/m/y H:i:s A');
    }
    public function getUpdatedUser()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser()->getUsername();
    }
}
```

Template file **additionalinfo.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \OX\HomeSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\AdditionalInfo $block */
$adminName = $block->getCurrentUser();
$createdAt = $block->getCreatedAt();
$updatedAt = $block->getUpdatedAt();
$updatedBy = $block->getUpdatedUser();
?>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper customer-information">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
        <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Information')) ?></span>
    </div>
    <table class="admin__table-secondary">
        <tbody>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created By:')) ?></th>
                <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($adminName) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Created At:')) ?></th>
                <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($createdAt) ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Updated At:')) ?></th>
                <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($updatedAt) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Updated By:')) ?></th>
                <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($updatedBy) ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


</div>
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$post['created_by'] = $user;
$post['updated_by'] = $user;
```

replace with this in save.php

```
if ($id) {
  $post['updated_by'] = $user;
}
else{
  $post['created_by'] = $user;
  $post['updated_by'] = $user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$post['created_by'] = $user;
$post['updated_by'] = $user;
```

***replace by***

```
if (!empty($id)) {
    $post['updated_by'] = $user;
} else {
    $post['created_by'] = $user;
    $post['updated_by'] = $user;
}
```